# Can't resolve symbol 'Defaulthttpclient' and 'Httppost' in android

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient, default, apache-httpclient-4.x

i build a new project.but i have a little problem.i can't use **DefaultHttpClient** and **HttpPost** even after i use it in my previous project already.

Is there any external librery i have to add?

i don't know how can i use both of this.

Help me for this issue.

My build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "Id"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
        compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
        compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
    }
```

Thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different DefaultHttpClient classes are available in the jars, you imported the wrong one,
Remove the import of **DefaultHttpClient** from your class file, and add this one,

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

One more thing, It should not be HttpPost, it will be HttpClient
complete example,

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
```

Comment: your answer help to solve my problem Thanks @Arsal imam