# Cannot resolve symbol DefaultHttpClient,HttpGet and HttpPost in android studio

Tags: java, android, httpclient

This question is not duplicate because I tried following solution.

[Cannot resolve symbol HttpGet,HttpClient,HttpResponce in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537108/cant-resolve-symbol-defaulthttpclient-and-httppost-in-android)

and

[Can't resolve symbol 'Defaulthttpclient' and 'Httppost' in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607257/cannot-resolve-symbol-httpget-httpclient-httpresponce-in-android-studio) solution in my application.

I add below 2 **dependencies** in my **gradle** file and **Sync** my project.

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

Still can't get solution.

after that I tried to **import** **`import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;`** manually. This solution can't help me.

Still not working. Please help me out.

**build.gradel**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<my Package>"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'

}
```

Comment: Did you check that Android Studio has access to the repository and actually tries to load the dependencies? Did you get any error messages etc.?

Comment: Post your `build.gradle ` & check above comments

Comment: `HttpClient` was deprecated in API Level 22

Comment: try legacy libray http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade-fo

Comment: The HttpClient dependencies that you are using are not [what Apache says that you should use](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html).

Comment: removed for the api level22, but id you want to use just change the api Level to 20 or some

Comment: Hey @Thomas I tried and check that there is no any error message when I sync above 2 dependencies.

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090899/androidhttpclient-and-httpget-api-deprecated-in-android-6-0-marshmallow-api-23