# issue with api code android studio

Tags: java, android, json

I am having some problems with my code. I have to read using JSONParser and I get this underlining on my code and it says that the problem is that i need try/catch clause but when I add the whole code is underlined and it says I have to do something with my api code.

Here is my code:

```
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
                            JSONArray quest=response.getJSONArray("students");
                            for(int i=0;i<quest.length();i++){
                                JSONObject question=quest.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name=question.getString("name");
                                String q=question.getString("question");


                                label.append(name+" asked "+ q);
                            }
                        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @JohnMiller The classes which you are using here are already **deprecated**, so don't use them.

Comment: Actually the HttpClient and HttpPost are deprecated and in API level 23 It was removed. that's why you got warnings in Android studio change your network connection to HttpURLConnection instead of HttpClient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling REST API from an android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339565/calling-rest-api-from-an-android-app)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288737/cannot-resolve-symbol-defaulthttpclient-httpget-and-httppost-in-android-studio Show for ref.

Comment: Huh, the *edit* is **not a means** to ask a **new, totally different** question (that is about your edit 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is suggested to use HttpUrlConnection instead, since HttpClient is deprecated.
For further research;
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 void hitService() {

        String resp = "";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String postURL = serviceUrl;

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);


            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            // Convert the response into a String
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            if (resEntity != null) {

                resp = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                Log.i(TAG, resp);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            uee.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
            cpe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resp;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient and HttpPost are deprecated and in API level 23 It was removed. that's why you got warnings in Android studio change your network connection to HttpURLConnection instead of HttpClient.

For implementation of HttpURLConnection check the [guide lines](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Even though you need to use HttpClient with target SDK =>23 Android gives a support with library for that you need to add following line to your build.gradel

```
 android{
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'}
```

**Note:** They are giving clear documentation of causes for removing HttpClient from Android and they are providing support and implementation of new Network connection [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#)